# user authentication in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-login

I found this following snippet of `code` in [Django documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests) for `log in`.
I have a different version below, which I want to know if it makes any difference from the above one.

I do a if `request.user` check. An `user` gets attached to `request` only if he is `authenticated/logged` in correct?

from `documentation`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

`my version:`

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

    def my_view(request):
        if request.user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

Comment: request.user would be `AnonymousUser` if user is not logged in. In your version, you are not authenticating the user for incorrect username/password. You can do `if request.user.is_authenticated()` to check if user is loGged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a huge difference between the two versions.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests),

```
If the current user has not logged in, this attribute will be set to an 
instance of AnonymousUser, otherwise it will be an instance of User.
```

so you would want:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # Do something for authenticated users.
else:
    # Do something for anonymous users.
```

Answer (score -2):

I put together a [quick and dirty Django project for user set up and auth with PostgresSQL](https://github.com/mdashley/django-rest-users.git). Feel free to check it out, especially the auth.py file in the users app. You can customize this to whatever best fits your project.